Convert HMAC signature from Go into R
I am trying to reproduce the following golang code in R for creating the signature for the consibio/mbtilesever. The aim is to build apps in R and python which can access mbtileservers uisng a secure connection. While I am able to generate a working version using python, a working version using R is proving tricky. Thanks in advance.
The sample GO code from the link above :

serviceId := "test"
date := "2019-03-08T19:31:12.213831+00:00"
salt := "0EvkK316T-sBLA"
secretKey := "YMIVXikJWAiiR3q-JMz1v2Mfmx3gTXJVNqme5kyaqrY"

key := sha1.New()
key.Write([]byte(salt + secretKey))

hash := hmac.New(sha1.New, key.Sum(nil))
message := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", date, serviceId)
hash.Write([]byte(message))

b64hash := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
fmt.Println(b64hash) // Should output: 2y8vHb9xK6RSxN8EXMeAEUiYtZk


In Python code is (working):
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

service_id = "test"
date = "2019-03-08T19:31:12.213831+00:00"
salt = "0EvkK316T-sBLA"
secret_key = "YMIVXikJWAiiR3q-JMz1v2Mfmx3gTXJVNqme5kyaqrY"

key = hashlib.sha1()
key.update((salt + secret_key).encode())

hash_obj = hmac.new(key.digest(), (date + ":" + service_id).encode(), hashlib.sha1)

b64_hash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash_obj.digest()).decode()
print(b64_hash)  # Should output: 2y8vHb9xK6RSxN8EXMeAEUiYtZk

The R code so far (not-working):
library(openssl)
library(digest)

service_id <- "test"
date <- "2019-03-08T19:31:12.213831+00:00"
salt <- "0EvkK316T-sBLA"
secret_key <- "YMIVXikJWAiiR3q-JMz1v2Mfmx3gTXJVNqme5kyaqrY"

key <- sha1(paste0(salt, secret_key))
hash_obj <- hmac(key, paste0(date, ":", service_id), "sha1")
b64_hash <- base64_encode(hash_obj)
print(b64_hash)  # Should output: 2y8vHb9xK6RSxN8EXMeAEUiYtZk



How about this?
library(digest)
library(base64enc)

service_id <- "test"
date       <- "2019-03-08T19:31:12.213831+00:00"
salt       <- "0EvkK316T-sBLA"
secret_key <- "YMIVXikJWAiiR3q-JMz1v2Mfmx3gTXJVNqme5kyaqrY"

key_digest  <- digest::digest(
  paste0(salt, secret_key), 
  algo = "sha1", 
  serialize = FALSE,
  raw = TRUE
)

hmac_binary <- digest::hmac(
  key_digest, 
  paste0(date, ":", service_id), 
  "sha1", 
  raw = TRUE
)

base64enc::base64encode(hmac_binary) # Should output: 2y8vHb9xK6RSxN8EXMeAEUiYtZk
#> [1] "2y8vHb9xK6RSxN8EXMeAEUiYtZk="

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice! One difference with this answer, and similarly with the python anwer is the '=' symbol at the end, whereas the original golang string does not contain this symobl. Trying other combinations of service_id, date, salt, secret_key and secret_key also produces a string with "=" at the end. Thoughts?

In the GO code the RawURLEncoding of base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString() strips the equal signs which are just padding. See here for a comparison to standard encoding.

testing the above, couple fo quirks appeared, where the r version returns the '+' instead of '-', and '/' instead of '_'. for example if the     service_id <- "fruit-salad"   , the r version should return "v1BND50T/mYHEfPz+59j1eMyBrs=", whereas say the py version returns "v1BND50T_mYHEfPz-59j1eMyBrs". currently fixing using gsub to clean the signature

Thanks for the follow up. I would not have expected those substitutions. I wonder if the server accepts either form.
